# Is there a way to make form letter variants in MSWord without VBA?

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2010

Is there a way to make form letter variants in MSWord without VBA? Specifically, I have a document that might include certain paragraphs or sentences (scattered throughout) depending on my exact purpose. My purpose isn't really a choice between 200 options, but more like a choice between 10 options for Factor A, 10 for Factor B, and 2 for Factor C. I would like to be able to manage and edit the document from a single place. Is this possible without VBA? How?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a document using OLE. These are the objects used by VBA.

But there's another way. Creating an XML document, which will be a document MS Office. In this case, the MS Word.

XML - that's fine. There are a number of XSLT processors, including the msxml. And most importantly the ability to convert one XML document into another XML.

Accordingly, we can come up with a convenient initial XML (template) that by converting the document will Wordml.

To generate MS Office not needed. Cross-platform.

Well now you can spread the fire and arrange the dance.

And some of the links below.

[Word Content Control Toolkit](https://archive.codeplex.com/?p=dbe)

[Transforming Open XML WordprocessingML to XHTML Using the Open XML SDK 2.0](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2010/ff628051%28v=office.14%29)

[Open XML SDK 2.0 for Microsoft Office](https://web.archive.org/web/20210506183710/http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=5124)

[Open XML scenarios](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/)

[Office 2003 Tool: WordprocessingML Transform Inference Tool](https://web.archive.org/web/20120917195233/http://www.microsoft.com:80/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=3412)

[Transforming XML to WordML](http://www.linkwerk.com/pub/xml/invitation/xml2wordml/)

[Stylesheets for converting Microsoft's WordprocessingML documents to XSL FO (XSLFO)](http://www.renderx.com/tools/word2fo.html)

[Document Generation using WordML (Word 2003)](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/)

## PDF! [Office 2003 XML Oreaily](https://web.archive.org/web/20140512164330/http://oreilly.com:80/catalog/officexml/chapter/ch02.pdf)

[Word 2003: XML Software Development Kit (SDK)](https://web.archive.org/web/20150706205911/http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=21923)

[Processing all Content Parts in an Open XML WordprocessingML Document](https://web.archive.org/web/20151112003627/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/ericwhite/archive/2010/07/02/processing-all-content-parts-in-an-open-xml-wordprocessingml-document.aspx)

[The Easy Way to Assemble Multiple Word Documents](https://web.archive.org/web/20160221091630/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/brian_jones/archive/2008/12/08/the-easy-way-to-assemble-multiple-word-documents.aspx)

[Create a rich Word document based on your own custom XML (without the need for XSLT)](https://web.archive.org/web/20150623231631/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/brian_jones/archive/2006/01/09/customxml1.aspx)

[Visual How To](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/)

Word 2007 Content Tollkit

[image: Word 2007 Content Tollkit]

Comment: I'm flabbergasted.  Thank you.  Spread the fire and arrange the dance?  This ritual seems even more complex than trying to pick up VBA!  However, it is gratifying to see that there is a path forward.

Comment: @RussellS.Pierce The path through the XML harder. In the old MSDN had a class diagram. Also, the topic was explained in detail by COM +. VBA is quite simple. You will have the opportunity to compare the generation of a document as XML, either directly or with the help of XSLT.There are situations when can not use VBA, and XML - better. Good luck.